# Is it safe to recover MetaMask wallet on new device by typing in seed phrase?

Tags: security, privacy, recovery

Security OpSec to guard against your wallet being compromised by bad actors says to **never type in your seed phrase on the keyboard of a device that is connected to the internet**.

Well, what if you have to recover your existing wallet on a new device after your laptop, smart phone or Ledger hardware wallet dies or gets lost for example?

Why would there be an exception to say that it is safe to type in your seed phrase only if you have to recover your wallet on a new device, but under no other circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

If you lost the device which has your wallet, you should recover your wallet on new device and this is the only way.
About Security OpSec's warning, it is because of hackers. After the wallet is developed, hackers understand that it is easy to steal the funds on the wallet by knowing the seed phrase.
The hackers install software which have screenshots or detect keyboard pressing and get seed phrase from it (because all the seed phrase words are known and words count for seed phrase are also known). And most times, users don't know if their device has this virus. So it is not a good idea to enter seed phrase again to the device that is connected to the internet. Sometimes those viruses are work as offline. lol
This is why Security OpSec is warning you. But you must enter the seed phrase again to the wallet.
So I think the best way is to buy a real new device, install OS again and double check if there's any virus. And then, you can type the seed phrase to the device and can recover your wallet!

Comment: Exactly, typing a seed phrase into a brand new device that has minimal probability of having a virus should be safe. Which basically means, only do wallet recovery on a brand new device. Buy a new device before doing wallet recovery (costly).